# C# cast non-generic class to generic base class regardless of type T

Tags: c#, generics

We want to convert a `List<Rule>` where we know they all derive from `BuildingRule<T>` into `BuildingRule<T>`, but the type T can be different.
We basically want to do
`_buildingRules.Find(x => ((BuildingRule<T>)x).GetBuilding(sku, upgradeId) != null)`
(the `.GetBuilding() != null is a requirement the rule has to meet in order for it to be the right one).

Though this does not work, and we were wondering if there is a way to achieve what we are trying to do.

````cs
public abstract class Rule
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public abstract string FileName { get; }
}

public abstract class BuildingRule<T> : Rule where T : BuildingDefinitionRule
{
    [XmlElement("Definition")]
    public virtual List<T> Definitions { get; set; }

    public virtual T GetBuilding(string sku, int upgradeId = 0)
    {
        return Definitions.Find(x => x.Sku == sku && x.UpgradeId == upgradeId);
    }
}

public abstract class BuildingRule : BuildingRule<BuildingDefinitionRule>
{
}```
````

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: We're using C# 10 and .NET 6 @GuruStron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create non-generic `BuildingRuleBase`:

```
public abstract class BuildingRuleBase : Rule
{
    public abstract BuildingDefinitionRule GetBuilding(string sku, int upgradeId = 0);
}
```

And inherit it:

```
public abstract class BuildingRule<T> : BuildingRuleBase where T : BuildingDefinitionRule
{
    public override T GetBuilding(string sku, int upgradeId = 0)
    {
        return Definitions.Find(x => true);
    }
}
```

And make `_buildingRules` a collection of `BuildingRuleBase`.

Or look into using [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) generic interfaces:

```
public interface IBuildingRule<out T> where T : BuildingDefinitionRule
{
    T GetBuilding(string sku, int upgradeId = 0);
}

public abstract class BuildingRule<T> : Rule, IBuildingRule<T> where T : BuildingDefinitionRule
{
    [XmlElement("Definition")]
    public virtual List<T> Definitions { get; set; }

    public T GetBuilding(string sku, int upgradeId = 0)
    {
        return Definitions.Find(x =>true);
    }
}
```

With `new List<IBuildingRule<BuildingDefinitionRule>>()` for type of `_buildingRules`.